# Add certain namespace to a SOAP Envelope in PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, namespaces

I really need to add a certain namespace to a SOAP Envelope which is not specified in the WSDL for some reason I already tryed using the 'uri' parameter in the SoapCliente constructor but it's not working

how can I add this namespace to the SoapEnvelope ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot [change the namespace](http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_envelope.asp) of the SoapEnvelope.

> Notice the xmlns:soap namespace in the example above. It should always have the value of: "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope".
>   The namespace defines the Envelope as a SOAP Envelope.
>   If a different namespace is used, the application generates an error and discards the message.